# Order de flexbox no funciona como debería

Tags: html, css, scss

Estoy teniendo un problema al usar `order` de flexbox al hacer responsive mi página: el problema está en que no me lo acomoda como yo quiero. Estoy leyendo una guía de [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) pero no me funciona.
Cabe recalcar que es dentro de media query, pero creo que debería funcionar porque estoy haciendo todo bien, no sé si capaz me falta alguna propiedad:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.grid-about{
    flex-direction: column;

    .about-item-img{
        display: inherit;
        width: 100%;

        .uno{
            order: 2;
        }

        .dos{
            order:4;

        }
        .tres{
            order: 6;
        }
    }

    .about-item-text{
        width: 100%;
        .uno{
            order: 1;
        }

        .dos{
            order: 3;
        }

        .tres{
            order: 5;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Y el html de mi página es así:

```
<section class="grid-about grey lighten-4">
<div class="about-item-text uno">
    <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, quas molestiae!</p>
</div>

<div class="about-item-img uno"></div>

<div class="about-item-img dos"></div>

<div class="about-item-text dos">
    <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, quas molestiae!</p>
</div>
<div class="about-item-text tres">
    <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, quas molestiae!</p>
</div>
<div class="about-item-img tres"></div>
```

No entiendo por qué no funciona.

Comment: Pero si estoy trabajndo con scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Además de lo que ha indicado [@fasuto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/255803/) en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/494005), y teniendo en cuenta que estás trabajando con SCSS, estás olvidando a un elemento importante al anidar selectores: al [selector padre `&`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector). Es útil en varias situaciones (como cuando se hace referencia tanto al selector padre como al hijo en un mismo elemento, para dar estilos a pseudo-elementos del mismo selector, entre otros).

Por lo tanto, los cambios a tu código serían los siguientes:

- Agregar `display: flex` a la clase `grid-about`. *
- Agregar `display: inherit` a `.about-item-text`, para que también sea *flex*. *
- Agregar el selector padre `&` a las clases  `uno`, `dos` y `tres`.

Haciendo los cambios, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid-about {
    display: flex; //----
    flex-direction: column;

    .about-item-img {
      display: inherit;
      width: 100%;

      &.uno { //----
        order: 2;
      }

      &.dos { //----
        order: 4;
      }
      &.tres { //----
        order: 6;
      }
    }

    .about-item-text {
      width: 100%;
      display: inherit; //----
      &.uno { //----
        order: 1;
      }

      &.dos { //----
        order: 3;
      }

      &.tres { //----
        order: 5;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sub>*: Fue lo indicado por el usuario mencionado en esta respuesta.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Asumieno que estas usando SCSS, te faltaria agregar `display: flex` en las clases **grid-about** y **about-item-text**, en esta ultima podrias heredarlo de la misma forma que en **about-item-img**, con `display: inherit`.

El codigo deberia quedar asi:

```
.grid-about{
    display: flex; // <--
    flex-direction: column;
    ...
    .about-item-text{
        display: inherit; // <--
        width: 100%;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Saludo!

Comment: Asumo que estara usando scss, por eso mi respuesta. Ahora mismo leo lo que me pasaste, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pero es un media query donde lo aplico, la clase principal ya contiene flex

Comment: Hice lo que sugeriste pero no cambio